# function for horizontal stack bar with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a horizontal stack bar but unable to do that also want to make alignment of bars dynamic like (horizontal,vertical).

also want to display N with labels like showed in pic below.

```
proba <- data.frame(PartnerName = c("China", "Brazil", "Argentina", "UE", "US"), Food = c("12%","22%","36%","40%","51"), Machinery = c("91%","78%","64%","60%","49%"), Total = c(26,28,43,34,25))
graph_data <- proba %>% select(-Total)
graph_data %>%  
  pivot_longer(-PartnerName)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=PartnerName, y=value, fill=name))+
  geom_bar(width = 0.9,stat="identity",position = "stack")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Code with some explanation (removed coord_flip) as suggested by @tjebo:

1. We create a `label_x` for our labels with `mutate` and `paste0`
2. Using `parse_number()` (my favorite function) we extract the number from xx%.
3. Bring data in long format with `pivot_longer()` (long format is the preferred format for ggplot2)
4. with geom_text we add the percent numbers to the bars.
5. Some tweaking: legend to bottom, remove labels x and y axis, and blank background.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr) # parse_number()
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer()
proba %>%  
  mutate(label_x = paste0(PartnerName, " N=", Total),
         across(c(Food, Machinery), parse_number)) %>% 
  arrange(Machinery) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Food, Machinery)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=label_x, fill=name))+
  geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_stack())+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value, "%")), position = position_stack(0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "steelblue"))+
  labs(x="", fill="", y="")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

data:

```
structure(list(PartnerName = c("China", "Brazil", "Argentina", 
"UE", "US"), Food = c("9%", "22%", "36%", "40%", "51"), Machinery = c("91%", 
"78%", "64%", "60%", "49%"), Total = c(26, 28, 43, 34, 25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**First answer:**
Something like this:

Be careful China 91% and 12% are not 100%

```
proba %>%  
  mutate(label_x = paste0(PartnerName, " N=", Total),
         across(c(Food, Machinery), parse_number)) %>% 
  arrange(Machinery) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Food, Machinery)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=label_x, y=value, fill=name))+
  geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_stack())+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value, "%")), position = position_stack(0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "steelblue"))+
  labs(x="", fill="", y="")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: it would be great if you could explain a bit what you're doing and not simply provide some code. Also, instead of using coord_flip, it would be much better to swap x and y aesthetic. It's less than ideal to promote the use of coord_flip in my opinion

Comment: @tjebo I will. Many thanks. First I wanted to check whether it is what OP is looking for.